# ClassCastException occured while using Comparator

Tags: comparator, classcastexception

I'm having trouble in understanding how to solve this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class Studente (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; Studente is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at redComp.compare(Corso.java:49)
    at Corso.minimo(Corso.java:33)
    at Corso.main(Corso.java:43)
```

This is class Studente's code:

```
class Studente {
    int matricola;
    int reddito;
    int eta;

    Studente(int matricola, int reddito, int eta) {
        this.matricola = matricola;
        this.reddito = reddito;
        this.eta = eta;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "matricola: " + matricola + ", reddito: " + reddito + ", eta: " + eta;
    }
}
```

This is class Corso's code:

```
public class Corso {

    Studente[] studenti;

    Corso(int n) {
        studenti = new Studente[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            studenti[i] = new Studente(i, i*10, i*2);
        }
    }

    Object minimo(Object a[], Comparator c) {
        Object max = new Object();
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if (c.compare(a[i],max)>0) {
              max = a[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Corso c= new Corso(5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.studenti));
        System.out.println("Il reddito minimo è: " + c.minimo(c.studenti, new redComp()));
    }
}

class redComp implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Studente)o1).reddito - ((Studente)o2).reddito;
    }
}
```

I think there are some casts missing but I didn't understand which ones exactly, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (c.compare(a[i],max)>0) {
```

Here, `max` has been instantiated as an `Object` a couple of lines before:

```
Object max = new Object();
```

Therefore, when you try to cast this to a `Studente` you hit the `ClassCastException`:

```
return ((Studente)o1).reddito - ((Studente)o2).reddito;
```

Consider how you can make sure `max` is actually a `Studente` (I'm assuming this is homework).

Comment: Yes, you're right... I literally have no idea how to inizialize that max.